# Mongodb stitch increase email confirmation URL expiry limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch, confirmation-email

As per documentation in https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/#send-a-confirmation-email

Currently, Mongodb stitch email confirmation URL expire in 30 mins which seems is not sufficient so like to know how to increase Mongodb stitch increase email confirmation URL expiry limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for security reason, 30 minutes should be enough for most users to open a new browser window, login, check incoming email, and click the confirmation link.

If the user miss the window of confirmation, you can always provide an ability for them to trigger another confirmation email using [resendConfirmationEmail()](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js/4/modules/userpasswordauthproviderclient.html#resendconfirmationemail)